# Is this multiple accesses to the same object between sequence points well-defined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is this multiple access allowed?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int A[1];
    A[0] = 0;
    A[A[0]] = 1;
    std::cout << A[0];
}
```

Refer to following paragraph...

> Except where noted, the order of evaluation of operands of individual
>   operators and subexpressions of individual expressions, and the
>   order in which side effects take place, is unspecified. Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall
>   have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an
>   expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to
>   determine the value to be stored. The requirements of this paragraph
>   shall be met for each allowable ordering of the subexpressions of a
>   full expression; otherwise the behavior is undefined.

If this uses the old value of A[0] it should be undefined behavior, right?

Comment: Compiled [here](http://ideone.com/VitzNp) for anyone who wants to play.

Comment: No, it is very defined and will print 1 to the screen

Comment: @Ben That isn't proof that it isn't undefined behaviour.

Comment: @NeilKirk I didnt say that it was.

Comment: There's no sequence point between reading `A[0]` and modifying `A[0]` as far as I know, so I would say UB.

Comment: Your question's title is totally useless. Improve it please.

Comment: @chris Why would you say there is no sequence point. From my understanding the ; implied a sequence point?

Comment: @Vality, Yes, but that's not between the reading and the modifying of `A[0]`.

Comment: I think this is fine, because side effects of the assignment are sequenced after evaluation of the operands.

Comment: @chris: Sequence points haven't existed for four years.

Comment: @chris, `A[A[0]]` cannot be evaluated without `A[0]` being evaluated first. That should force evaluation of `A[0]` to be sequenced ahead of the assignment.

Comment: It doesn't seem _possible_ to evaluate it in two different, conflicting ways.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, They exist in the OP's referred text. Anyway, I take my comment back, as it would mean `i = i;` is undefined.

Comment: If that quote comes from a C++ standard, then it's rather out-of-date: the concept of a "sequence point" was removed in C++11 (replaced by a more thread-friendly notion of sequencing). In any case, each statement is sequenced before the next one, and each assignment is sequenced after the evaluation of its operands, so there are no unsequenced accesses here.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'm studying for a test

Comment: @chris: The OP's "referred text" is out of date.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes, it's valid.**

First of all, reading `A[0]` on the LHS of the assignment is perfectly valid and well-defined for the same reason that this is:

```
int x = 42;
x = x + 1;
```

Both operands must be evaluated before the assignment can be executed.

Secondly, evaluating `A[A[0]]` in isolation is quite okay:

> `[C++11: 1.9/15]:` *[..]* The value computations of the operands of an
>   operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator. *[..]*

In C++03 the closest related wording I can find is the following regarding assignment (though there are examples of constructs such as `a = a + x` all over the gaff):

> `[C++03: 5.17/8]:` If the value being stored in an object is accessed from another object that overlaps in any way the storage of the first object, then the overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall have the same type,  otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Comment: For pedantic purposes as there are many shops not yet using C++11, is there a corresponding statement in the previous standard? Everything I see so far leads me to believe in C++98/03 it is in fact UB.

Comment: @MarkB: C++03 has examples of e.g. `a = a + x` all over it, but I'll find a specific quote for you if I can.